# Who currently owns Stack Exchange?

Tags: support, company

Is it Prosus, a Netherlands-based subsidiary of South African media company Naspers, who announced a deal to acquire Stack Overflow for $1.8 billion?

Answer (score 3):

This can be summed up with this banner generated by Google:

[image: banner showing Stack Exchange Inc. as the company with Prosus as parent organization]

Stack Exchange is owned by a company called *Stack Exchange, Inc.*, and Prosus is the parent organization of that company, but does not directly own Stack Exchange.